# Org2blog & WP-Syntax plugin

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to send source code from within Org2blog with `#+INCLUDE`
to the WP-Syntax plugin, and that one requires tags like:

```
<pre language="foo"></pre> tags.
```

When I write an include like:

```
#+INCLUDE "./foo.py" src
```

it puts out tags like:

```
<pre class="src src-fundamental"></pre>
```

How could I change that?

Comment: Where should it put the `<pre>` tags? Could you please give an example?

Comment: The <pre> tags are of course part of the HTML output which Org creates from "#+INCLUDE "foo" src". How could I manipulated them?

Answer (score 3):

- Set the variable `org2blog/wp-use-sourcecode-shortcode`.
- Add the language after the `src` keyword. For example `#+INCLUDE: "~/.emacs" src emacs-lisp`

For more info look at the [org-manual page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html)